# Unwanted Gap Between jquery fadeIn and FadeOut

Tags: jquery

I currently have a hand-built slider in my app that is functioning with jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.  However, inbetween slides it is flashing the background image for a split second between white slides (which is very distracting).

How do I get rid of the time gap between slides?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="hero-image-row-index">
  <div class="hero-image-outer-index text-center">
    <div class="hero-image-inner-index text-center">
      <%= image_tag 'Background 1.jpg', id: "hero-image-index", class: "hero-image-index", alt: "Beautiful Sunset over Pelican Hills Golf Course and Ocean Cliffs" %>
      <%= image_tag 'Background 1.jpg', id: "hero-image-index-2", class: "hero-image-index", style: "display: none", alt: "Beautiful Sunset over Pelican Hills Golf Course and Ocean Cliffs" %>
    </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
  </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
</div> <!-- row -->

<div id="overlap-hero-image-index">
  <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-1">
        <h1 class="font-accent color-white mt-5 mb-4" style="font-size: 52px">Genetic Golf</h1>
        <h2 class="color-white">We&nbsp;don't&nbsp;guess, we test to find what works best&nbsp;for&nbsp;you!</h2>
      </div> <!-- slide 1 -->

      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-2" style="display: none; border-bottom: thick #567e3a solid; background-color: white">
        <h2 style="color: black; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">The greatest golfers of all time have different swings.<br>None of them have the perfect swing!</h2>
        <%= image_tag 'ss01.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss02.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss03.jpg' %>
      </div> <!-- slide 2 -->

      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-3" style="display: none; border-bottom: thick #567e3a solid; background-color: white">
        <h2 style="color: black; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">The great ones have a swing that matched their body and mind.<br>They unlocked their genetic golf code.</h2>
        <%= image_tag 'ss04.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss05.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss06.jpg' %>
      </div> <!-- slide 3 -->

      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-4" style="display: none; border-bottom: thick #567e3a solid; background-color: white">
        <h2 style="color: black; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">Genetic Golf is a true paradigm shift in learning golf.<br>We run specific tests to find what works best for you!</h2>
        <%= image_tag 'ss07.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss08.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss09.jpg' %>
      </div> <!-- slide 4 -->

      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-5" style="display: none; border-bottom: thick #567e3a solid; background-color: white">
        <h2 style="color: black; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">A golf swing has over 2 billion options.<br>Genetic Golf takes out the guess work.</h2>
        <%= image_tag 'ss10.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss11.jpg' %>
        <%= image_tag 'ss12.jpg' %>
      </div> <!-- slide 5 -->

      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-6" style="display: none; border-bottom: thick #567e3a solid; background-color: white">
        <h2 style="color: black; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">You can spend a lifetime searching for&nbsp;your&nbsp;swing<br>or take a simple Genetic Golf&nbsp;evaluation.</h2>
        <%= image_tag 'icon_yourid.png' %>
        <%= image_tag 'icon_dynamics.png' %>
        <%= image_tag 'icon_TEMP_yourcode.jpg' %>
      </div> <!-- slide 6 -->

      <div class="slide text-center" id="slide-7" style="display: none">
        <h2 style="color: white; padding-top: 30px; font-weight: bold">Unlock your personal Genetic Golf code today!</h2>
        <h2 style="font-size: 40px; color: white; font-weight: bolder; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px">Find your game!<br>Great shots, great days,<br>and great memories!</h2>
      </div> <!-- slide 7 -->
    </div> <!-- slides -->

    <div class="controller">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div> <!-- controller -->
  </div> <!-- slideshow container -->
</div> <!-- overlap hero image -->
```

And the jQuery is like this:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Hides all images except for one, the one is given by an
    // index. Also updates the controller.
    function showSlide(index) {
      $('.slides .slide').each(function(i) {
        if (i == index) {
          $(this).delay(400).fadeIn(500);
        } else {
          $(this).fadeOut(500);
        }
      });

      var spans = $('.controller span').removeClass('active');
      spans.eq(index).addClass('active');
    }

    // Show only the first element and set an interval to
    // continue to cycle through elements.
    var index = 0;
    showSlide(index);

    var intervalFunc = function() {
      index = index >= $('.slides .slide').length ? 0 : index + 1;
      showSlide(index);
    };
    var interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 6000);

    // Handle clicks which will reset the interval to each time.
    $('.controller span').click(function() {
      // Set the current picture.
      index = $(this).index();
      showSlide(index);

      // Reset the interval
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = setInterval(intervalFunc, 6000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me get rid of the weird gap?  I'm still decently new to jQuery so none of my troubleshooting attempts have worked.

Comment: have you tried using .fadeIn('fast')?

Comment: @AkshayRathnavas That just speeds the fade, but doesn't change the gap.

Comment: What browser(s) does this occur in? Also, for someone to help, you'll likely need to set up a full working example in something like Codepen

Comment: @KayakinKoder It shows in chrome and safari.  You can see it here:  https://genetic-golf.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Ok, you may have much better luck getting help (from  me included) if you follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Basically, reducing your problem down to the very bare bones, makes it much easier for others to debug. A link to your website...that's far from a minimum example. Also, I very often find when creating a minimal reproducible example that I find the problem myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving `background-color` to the `<div>` with `id overlap-hero-image-index` or `<div>` with `class slideshow-container`. This won't remove the gap of `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` but will resolve your problem of showing background between whites.

```
#overlap-hero-image-index{
    background-color: white;
}
// OR
.slideshow-container{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: The first one definitely works to get rid of the awkward gap, but it also covers up the image I need to see on the first and last slides.  The second doesn't change anything.  But this gives me ideas to work with...

Comment: Well, in that case, glad that I could be of help. :)

Comment: I ended up using #1 and giving the first and last slides background images to go on top of the white background.  Thanks!